# Linked List C with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to push an element in a linked list, then print it but the problem received is: `segmentation fault`.

I've created struct `libro`, `cella` and `lista`. Then in function `insHead` i've tried to insert an element to the list, taking input from user and then in function `printList` (and here i've got the segmentation fault) i would print list's elements.

The code is:

```
typedef struct libro {
    char titolo[64];
    char autore[32];
    short inLibreria;
    short fuoriLibreria;
    short id;
} Libro;

typedef struct cella {
    Libro libro;
    struct cella *pNext;
} Cella;

typedef Cella *Pcella;

typedef struct listaLibri{
    Cella *pFirst;
    Cella *pLast;
} ListaLibri;

void insHead(ListaLibri lista){
    Pcella cella;
    Libro libro;
    printf("Inserisci titolo libro: ");
    scanf("%s",  libro.titolo);
    printf("Inserisci autore libro: ");
    scanf("%s",  libro.autore);
    printf("Inserisci il numero di copie presenti in libreria: ");
    scanf("%d",&libro.inLibreria);
    if(lista.pFirst == NULL){
        cella = NULL;
        Pcella temp = cella;
        cella = malloc(sizeof(Cella));
        (*cella).libro = libro;
        (*cella).pNext = temp;
        lista.pFirst = cella;
        lista.pLast = cella;
    }
    printList(lista);
}

void printList(ListaLibri *lista){
    Pcella cella = lista->pFirst;
    Pcella temp = cella;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%s", temp->libro.autore);
        temp = temp->pNext;
    }
    free(cella);
    free(temp);
}

void main(){
    ListaLibri lista;
    insHead(lista);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to initialize `lista.pFirst` and `lista.pLast` with `NULL`.

```
int main()
{
    ListaLibri lista;
    lista.pFirst = NULL;  // <- init NULL
    lista.pLast = NULL;   // <- init NULL

    insHead( &lista );    // <- pass pointer to list to function insHead
    insHead( &lista );
    .....       

    deleteList( &lista ); 
    return 0;
}
```

The input paramter to your function `insHead` has to be an in and output paramter. Otherwise you would pass an copy of `lista` to function `insHead` and never get back its content.

```
void insHead( ListaLibri *lista )
                     // ^ input and outout paramter
{
    if ( lista == NULL )
        return;

    Cella *head = lista->pFirst;           // remember head of list
    lista->pFirst = malloc(sizeof(Cella)); // allocate new node right to target
    lista->pFirst->pNext = head;           // successor of new node is head of list
    if ( lista->pLast == NULL )            // if list was empty new node is tail of list
        lista->pLast = lista->pFirst;

    Libro libro;
    printf("Inserisci titolo libro: ");
    scanf("%s",  libro.titolo);
    printf("Inserisci autore libro: ");
    scanf("%s",  libro.autore);
    printf("Inserisci il numero di copie presenti in libreria: ");
    scanf("%d",&libro.inLibreria);
    lista->pFirst->libro = libro;

    printList( lista );
}
```

Don't delete nodes infunction print.

```
void printList(ListaLibri *lista)
{
    if ( lista == NULL )
        return;

    Pcella temp = lista->pFirst;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", temp->libro.autore);
        temp = temp->pNext;
    }
}
```

Write a function which deletes the list.

```
void deleteList(ListaLibri *lista)
{
    if ( lista == NULL )
        return;

    Pcella temp = lista->pFirst;
    while (temp != NULL)           // terminate if tail of list is reached
    {
        Pcella next = temp->pNext; // rmember successor of node
        free( temp );              // delete node
        temp = next;               // go to next node
    }
    lista->pFirst = NULL;
    lista->pLast = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the `pFirst` value, so it is having garbage data, which is not equal to `NULL`.
Modify your code like this;

```
void insHead(ListaLibri lista)
{
    // Your code goes here

    lista.pFirst = NULL;
    if(lista.pFirst == NULL)
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
    printList(&lista); //Pass it as a reference, because printList() input parameter is a pointer type.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You declare lista in main, but you don't initialize any fields.  My guess is that lista.pFirst is non-NULL garbage and you if is then skipped.